# How do you efficiently return all of a list but one element?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a problem that I am working on that requires that I compare several lists of overlapping data points. As I traverse one of the lists, I'd like to only compare those data to the other lists, and not itself. So, how does one efficiently do this, especially if it must be done potentially hundreds of times? Obviously, if I can control the order in which I make the comparisons, any method would work as I can limit the number of times this has to be done. But, I can't necessarily guarantee the order.

Now both [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Drop.html?q=Drop&lang=en) and [`Take`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Take.html?q=Take&lang=en) could be used for this, but I'm interested to know if they are the fastest methods to do this, or is there something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Most[list]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Most.html?q=Most&lang=en) to do this if you want to drop last element, [`Rest[list]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rest.html?q=Rest&lang=en) to drop the first element, and [`Delete[list, n]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Delete.html?q=Delete&lang=en) to drop the $n^\mathrm{th}$ element.

I verified that none of these unpack packed arrays, so performance should be good.  `Drop` and `Take` don't unpack either, so the performance of those should be similar too, at least for packed arrays.

Comment: Ah, forgot about `Delete`.

Comment: `Rest[]` drops the first element, being complementary to `First[]`. Analogously, `Most[]` pairs nicely with `Last[]`...

Comment: On `Delete[]` vs. `Drop[]`: `Delete[Range[5], 3]` and `Drop[Range[5], {3}]` do the same thing, of course.

Answer (score 9):

All the above are useful when you know the position of elements. Another frequent case is when you do not know the position, but know the type or value:

```
In[1]:= DeleteCases[Range[5], 2]    
Out[1]= {1, 3, 4, 5}

In[2]:= DeleteCases[Range[15], x_ /; 10 < x < 14]    
Out[2]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15}

In[3]:= DeleteCases[{3, rr, "space", 3, 5, t}, "space"]
Out[3]= {3, rr, 3, 5, t}

In[4]:= DeleteCases[{W, XYZ, 3 + I 5, "wer", 1.5, 1/6}, _Complex]
Out[4]= {W, XYZ, "wer", 1.5, 1/6}

In[5]:= DeleteCases[{1, f[2, 3], 4}, f, {2}, Heads -> True]
Out[5]= {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: For numerical lists, the problem is that `DeleteCases` will unpack. So it is only efficient for unpacked lists and general symbolic expressions. If you deal with numerical lists, there are ways to efficiently extract a position of an element without unpacking (the most efficient being probably the compiled-to-C code). Then use `Delete`.

Answer (score 9):

Using `Drop`, `Take`, `Most`, etc. are fine but also consider the expresiveness of `Part` or `[[]]`

Here are some examples:

```
list = {3, 6, 9, 12};

In[532]:= list[[{1, 2, 3}]]

Out[532]= {3, 6, 9}

In[534]:= list[[1 ;; 3]]

Out[534]= {3, 6, 9}

In[535]:= list[[Range[Length[list] - 1]]]

Out[535]= {3, 6, 9}

In[536]:= list[[{3, 2, 1}]]

Out[536]= {9, 6, 3}

In[537]:= list[[{1, 3, 1, 1, 1}]]

Out[537]= {3, 9, 3, 3, 3}
```

Comment: One particularly neat thing about `Part[]` is that it allows for a *parallel assignment* construction like `list[[1 ;; 3]] = list[[3 ;; 1 ;; -1]]`.

Comment: But, how do you return everything but the `9` out of your list using `Part`?

Comment: -1 Doesn't appear to answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative I had in mind when I wrote the question was to use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html) alongside [`Permutations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Permutations.html). `Pick` allows you to specify a mask that can be used to select elements from a list,

```
In[] := Pick[(data = {a, b, c, d, e, f}), {1,1,0,0,0,1}, 1]
Out[]:= {a, b, f}
```

and `Permuations` can be used to generate such a mask,

```
In[] := Permutations[{0}~Join~Array[1&, Length@data - 1]]
Out[]:= {{0,1,1,1,1}, {1,0,1,1,1}, {1,1,0,1,1}, {1,1,1,0,1}, {1,1,1,1,0}}
```

Then,

```
Pick[
   (data = {a, b, c, d, e, f}), #, 1
 ]& /@ Permutations[{0}~Join~Array[1&, Length@data - 1]]
```

returns

```
{{b, c, d, e, f}, {a, c, d, e, f}, 
 {a, b, d, e, f}, {a, b, c, e, f}, 
 {a, b, c, d, f}, {a, b, c, d, e}}
```

Alternatively, [`IdentityMatrix[Length@data]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IdentityMatrix.html) could be used

```
Pick[data, #, 0]& /@ IdentityMatrix[Length@data]
```

where the pattern has been changed from `1` to `0`.

Comment: is it basically just the diagonal that you want excluded @rcollyer?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, pretty much. But, I expected to have to perform it a lot more often than what I've shown. In review, probably not as much as I thought.

Comment: rcollyer's message at 7:18 on the 18th appears to be missing a 0 in the mask: `Pick[(data = {a, b, c, d, e, f}), {1,1,0,0,1}, 1]` produces the message `"Pick::incomp: "Expressions {a,b,c,d,e,f} and {1,1,0,0,1} have incompatible shapes""`

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear whether your answer to your question represents the real problem or just an example but another way to get permutations that exclude the diagonal is to use `ListCorrelate`:

```
ListCorrelate[{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, 1]

{b + c + d + e + f, a + c + d + e + f, a + b + d + e + f, 
 a + b + c + e + f, a + b + c + d + f, a + b + c + d + e}
```

That isn't what you want obviously but my long winded explanation starts with the general form of the above:

```
ListCorrelate[{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, {1, 1}, {a, b, 
  c, d, e, f}, Times, Plus]

{b + c + d + e + f, a + c + d + e + f, a + b + d + e + f, 
 a + b + c + e + f, a + b + c + d + f, a + b + c + d + e}
```

So you can get an answer by using a function other than `Plus` in the generalized `ListCorrelate`:

```
g[x__] := DeleteCases[{x}, 0] (* or g= DeleteCases[{##}, 0] & *)

ListCorrelate[{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, {1, 1}, {a, b, 
  c, d, e, f}, Times, g]

{{b, c, d, e, f}, {c, d, e, f, a}, {d, e, f, a, b}, {e, f, a, b, 
  c}, {f, a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d, e}}
```

I really like `ListCorrelate` but unfortunately the generalized form is much slower than the default form -- you may find it up to 2 or more orders of magnitude slower depending on your problem [plea to Wolfram: make the generalized form of `ListCorrelate` run fast -- there is so much it could be useful for]. So the alternative in a case like this may be to revert to the default form and replace `Plus` in the result:

```
ListCorrelate[{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, 1] /. Plus -> List

{{b, c, d, e, f}, {a, c, d, e, f}, {a, b, d, e, f}, {a, b, c, e, 
  f}, {a, b, c, d, f}, {a, b, c, d, e}}
```

Answer (score 3):

An update from **v13.1** worth adding here is [**DeleteElements**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteElements.html)

With a list

```
list = RandomInteger[{-1, 11}, 13]
```

> `{8, 7, 0, 10, 3, 0, 7, 2, 3, 5, -1, 3, 3}`

let's say that we want to remove the number `3` altogether, or once, or twice. We have, respectively

```
DeleteElements[list, {3}]
```

> `{8, 7, 0, 10, 0, 7, 2, 5, -1}`

This is, of course, equivalent to `DeleteCases[list, 3]`

```
DeleteElements[list, 1 -> {3}]
```

> `{8, 7, 0, 10, 0, 7, 2, 3, 5, -1, 3, 3}`

```
DeleteElements[list, 2 -> {3}]
```

> `{8, 7, 0, 10, 0, 7, 2, 5, -1, 3, 3}`

Finally, let's say that we want to remove 3 times the 3 and 2 times the 0

```
DeleteElements[list, {3, 2} -> {3, 0}]
```

> `{8, 7, 10, 7, 2, 5, -1, 3}`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {3, 6, 9, 12, 6};
```

There are, of course, many more possibilities. Some of them are:

**Operator form of DeleteCases**

```
DeleteCases[6] @ list
```

{3, 9, 12}

**Select + FreeQ**

```
Select[FreeQ @ 6] @ list
```

{3, 9, 12}

**ReplaceAt**

```
 ReplaceAt[list, 6 :> Nothing, All]
```

{3, 9, 12}

**Query**

```
Query[{1, 3, 4}] @ list
```

{3, 9, 12}

By using `Alternatives` we can drop 2 or more elements, for example:

```
DeleteCases[3 | 6] @ list
```

{9, 12}

Comment: Very nice. I forgot about `ReplaceAt` and `Query` completely...

Comment: I'm a close friend of `DeleteElements` though, because it provides a maximum of control as you showed in your answer.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed. It is very convenient!