# Why is Neptune missing from AstronomicalData?

Tags: curated-data, astronomy

An old notebook I've recently started working with has a strange error: Prior to version 8, a figure I generated using `Drop[AstronomicalData["Planet"],-1]` to display all of the currently recognized planets, along with some other data, worked fine, but in version 8, Neptune is missing. Is this a bug in 8, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry if this is rude, but that should not have been difficult to debug.  Did you try to examine it at all before posting?

Comment: Yes, always. I was even kind of proud for zeroing in on AstronomicalData as the likely offender (my code is pretty wooly), and even turned on "show changes" in the AstronomicalData documentation, but didn't catch it there (it's not called out).

Comment: Don't feel bad, [everyone](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174/52) (well, [almost everyone](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin)) has asked a question with an answer that is obvious after the fact. It hurts the ego a little, but it is recoverable.

Comment: @rcollyer: I think my ego deserves a bit of crushing on this one: after all, I managed to look right at the solution without managing to realize that $-1-1=-2$.

Comment: Ow. that would sting a little. BTW, I like your pseudonym.

Comment: I always thought Pluto, in a fit of pique, would eventually bump Neptune right out of the solar system. It was just a matter of timing. Alignment of the planets and so forth..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`AstronomicalData` was updated to remove Pluto, so you don't need to anymore.

```
In[27]:= AstronomicalData["Planet"]

Out[27]= {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"}
```

Answer (score 13):

It's been demoted to a "dwarf planet", a splendid way of avoiding saying it's not a planet like Jupiter. From the documentation in Mathematica 8:

[image: Sadly demoted Pluto]

Comment: And then you can check out `AstronomicalData["DwarfPlanet"]`.